# Cannot list image publishers from Azure java SDK

Tags: java, azure, sdk

I'm using the Azure ARM API and I'm trying to list all publishers by location through the Azure Java SDK, by executing the following code:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.ComputeManagementClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.ComputeManagementService;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.VirtualMachineImageListPublishersParameters;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.VirtualMachineImageResourceList;

@Test
public void testListPublishers() {
    ComputeManagementClient client = ComputeManagementService.create(createConfiguration());
    VirtualMachineImageListPublishersParameters params = new VirtualMachineImageListPublishersParameters();
    params.setLocation("westus");
    VirtualMachineImageResourceList response = client.getVirtualMachineImagesOperations().listPublishers(params);
    ArrayList<VirtualMachineImageResource> resources = response.getResources();
    System.out.println("Found publishers: " + resources.size());
}
```

This results in the following request:

```
GET /subscriptions/{some-subscription}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/westus/publishers?api-version=2015-06-15
```

However, I always get and empty list, no matter the location I put in the publisher parameters.
I am able to list other resources with the same client, so it is not an issue in creating the client.

Do you have any suggestions of what I might be doing wrong? Perhaps there is a permission that I don't have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, the issue was caused by the application registed on Azure AD has no Reader role. I reproduced the issue, and resolved it via assign a Reader role to the AzureAD app.

There are two way for assigning a Reader role.

1. Using Azure-CLI with arm mode, and command `azure ad role assignment create --objectId <objectId of the aad app> -o Reader -c /subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/`

> If you don't know the objectId of the AzureAD app, you can command `azure ad sp show --search <the aad app name>` to review it. If you have no `Service Principal (SP)` for Azure AD, you can command `azure ad sp create <clientId>` to create it.

2. Add the role and user via `All settings -> RESOURCE MANAGEMENT -> Users` when the application shown on Azure new portal, please see the pics below.

Select a role `Reader` :
[image]

Add a user by searching name:
[image]

After assign the Reader role to the aad app, you can list the image publishers as your wish.

Comment: And is there a reason why I cannot see the application (created in the old portal) in the new portal? Should I create it once again in the new portal?

Comment: @vdimitrov No. I'm not sure whether your app registed on AAD as WebApp or others deployed on Azure, so I gave two ways for different scenarios. Please try to do the first one preferentially.

Comment: The problem was, that I had to assign the Reader role to the subscription. So if anyone hits this, go to the new portal, select the subscription and then Access -> Add -> Select roles (Reader, Owner, Contributor, whatever) -> on the Add users section search by the application name (not displayed by default).

Btw, for some reason, the CLI threw the following error for some reason - 'role' is not an azure command, even though I was in ARM mode.

Much thanks for your input!